# Is it possible to convert the information stored already in your table database into different languages in C# MVC or XAML

Tags: c#, sql, xaml

I have a table in my database which contains `varchar` and `text` columns.

Is it possible to convert the `varchar` already stored from my database to different languages like French or Spanish?

I have created `Localization.xml` but that is not working. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Comment: [Why “is it possible?” is a poor question](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7273/).

Comment: You think the Localization.xml should automatically translate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really, you'd need to store each variant in the database.

Most localization features for .NET are for localizing UI not data.

If you really do want to try translating data on-the-fly from your database to show to a user you could look at some of the online translation APIs like: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/translator/translatorapi.aspx